# Создать dql запрос к базе

Tags: mysql, orm, symfony3, sonata

Как можно создать `dql` запрос к базе в `SonataAdmin`. У меня есть `mySQL` запрос, его нужно перевести в `dql`, или как-то заюзать его в таком формате, но я не знаю как

```
SELECT ca.id, cu.card AS cu_id 
FROM card ca 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer cu ON ca.id = cu.card 
WHERE cu.id IS NULL
```

Comment: емнип в DQL условия связывания пишутся не как ON clause, а как WITH clause: `SELECT card.id, customer.card AS cu_id FROM card LEFT JOIN customer WITH card.id = customer.card WHERE customer.id IS NULL`

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать:

```
            ->add(
            'card',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'MainBundle:Card',
                'multiple' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('ca')
                        ->select('ca')
                        ->leftJoin('MainBundle\Entity\Customer', 'cu', 'WITH', 'ca.id = cu.card')
                        ->where('cu.id IS NULL')
                        ->groupBy('ca.id');
                },
            ]
        )
```